Failed to run mapping and navigation in ROS 2 Jazzy
I'm trying to port https://github.com/atinfinity/megarover_samples_ros2 to ROS 2 Jazzy.

Humble: https://github.com/atinfinity/megarover_samples_ros2
Jazzy(develop): https://github.com/atinfinity/megarover_samples_ros2/tree/prepare-jazzy

My environment is as follows.

ROS 2 Jazzy
Gazebo Harmonic

mkdir -p ~/dev_ws/src
cd ~/dev_ws/src
git clone https://github.com/atinfinity/megarover_samples_ros2.git -b prepare-jazzy
cd ..
rosdep install -y -i --from-paths src/megarover_samples_ros2
colcon build --symlink-install
source ~/dev_ws/install/setup.bash
ros2 launch megarover_samples_ros2 vmegarover_with_sample_world.launch.py
ros2 launch megarover_samples_ros2 vmegarover_mapping.launch.py

As a result, I could launch Gazebo Simulator.
But, it failed to do mapping.
I could subscribe /scan and odom topic.
ros2 topic echo /scan --no-arr
header:
  stamp:
    sec: 5
    nanosec: 750000000
  frame_id: front_lrf_link
angle_min: -3.140000104904175
angle_max: 3.140000104904175
angle_increment: 0.006286286283284426
time_increment: 0.0
scan_time: 0.0
range_min: 0.05999999865889549
range_max: 10.0
ranges: '<sequence type: float, length: 1000>'
intensities: '<sequence type: float, length: 1000>'

$ ros2 topic echo /odom --no-arr
header:
  stamp:
    sec: 58
    nanosec: 160000000
  frame_id: odom
child_frame_id: base_footprint
pose:
  pose:
    position:
      x: 3.601075709958785e-11
      y: -8.215186436465076e-26
      z: 0.0
    orientation:
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: -8.091844303243027e-16
      w: 1.0
  covariance: '<array type: double[36]>'
twist:
  twist:
    linear:
      x: 4.85272291820196e-19
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
    angular:
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: -1.6856421776829876e-18
  covariance: '<array type: double[36]>'

But, I could not subscribe /map topic.
$ ros2 topic echo /map


Can you show us your frames with ros2 run tf2_tools view_frames

@yigitboracagiran Thank you for your reply. I checked this point. https://gist.github.com/atinfinity/0ace427de4133d032cd43e22bcf3f827

You can't subscribe the map because it doesn't exist

I launch ros2 launch slam_toolbox online_sync_launch.py. There is no problem.
https://github.com/SteveMacenski/slam_toolbox/blob/jazzy/launch/online_sync_launch.py
